# How to overwrite a dictionary (list of key-val pairs) in SWI-prolog?

Tags: dictionary, prolog

Here's my problem:

I have a key-val pair dictionary similar to this (more pairs in real codes):

```
args = [(score, 0), (multiplier, 1), (reward, 0), (prior_prob, 1)].
```

I defined two functions to work with the dictionary:

```
% look up the Val of a Key in a Dict 
lookup(Key,Dict,Val):-
    member((Key,Val), Dict).
```

and

```
% update(Key, NewVal, Dict, NewDict) updates the value of a key in the dict

update(Key,Val,[],[(Key,Val)]).               % Add new pair to current dict
update(Key,Val,[(Key,_)|Rest], [(Key,Val)|Rest]):- !. % Found the key and update the value
update(Key,Val,[KV|Rest],[KV|Result]) :-      % recursively look for the key 
    update(Key,Val,Rest,Result).
```

The reason I need a dictionary is that I have many functions that need those arguments (such as "score", "multiplier", etc.). Those functions call each other and pass on the arguments. Not all the arguments are needed by every function, but many of them are, and some are updated more often than the others. So this dictionary is basically a list of arguments wrapped up as a package that needs to be passed around and overwritten frequently. For example, without the dictionary, I may have this (made-up) function:

```
calculate('cond1', 'cond2', S0, S1, Multiplier, Reward, Prior):-
    getscore('cond1', 'cond2', S0, S1, Multiplier, Reward, Prior).

getscore('cond1', 'cond2', S0, S1, Multiplier, Reward, Prior):-
    reward('cond1', 'cond2', Reward),  % look up rewards based on conditions
    MultNew is Multiplier*Prior,       % calculate the new multiplier
    S1 is (S0+Rewards*MultNew).        % update score
```

But with a dictionary, I can have:

```
calculate2('cond1', 'cond2', Args, NewArgs):-
    getscore2('cond1', 'cond2', Args, NewArgs).

getscore2('cond1', 'cond2', Args, NewArgs):-
    reward('cond1', 'cond2', Reward), 
    lookup(prior, Args, Prior),
    lookup(multiplier, Args, Mult),
    update(reward, Reward, Args),
    MultNew is Multiplier*Prior,
    update(multiplier, MultNew, Args, NewArgs),
    update(score, S0+Reward*MultNew, Args, NewArgs).
```

(The second way looks longer and slower than the first, but since in reality, not all args need to be updated or looked up all at once, and since it's more flexible to add more parameters later, I think it's better to have the dictionary. Plz let me know if there's better design choice) When I run it, I get:

```
No permission to modify static procedure `(=)/2'
```

at the line number where I defined the dictionary args.

I tried `:-dynamic(arg/0, update/4, lookup/3).`, which is no use.

What does (=)/2 mean here? How to permit overwriting a dictionary in Prolog? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to change `args` to `Args`

Comment: @damianodamiano You mean change to `Args = [(score,0), ...]`? But when we do query later we need to query facts not variables, don't we? Also, that would result in a 'Singleton Variable'. Sorry I'm a bit confused. Please point out if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: What will be your query for instance?

Comment: @damianodamiano Say, if we do `test(NewArgs):-calculate2('cond1', cond2', args, NewArgs).` The third field `args` needs to be a knowledge base for an answer, not a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the (possible) solution for your problem (in **SWI-Prolog**).
The dictionary is implemented using **SWI-Prolog** embedded database (non-persistent)

It's the set of term chains. Terms are associated with user-supplied **key**

```
%key `small int` or `atom`-
lookup(Key, Value) :-
    current_key( Key ),
    recorded( Key, Value, _ ) -> 
    true
    ;
    recordz(Key, Value).

update( Key, OldValue, NewValue ) :-
    same_term( OldValue, NewValue ) -> 
    true
    ;
    (current_key( Key ),
    recorded( Key, OldValue, Ref ase( Ref )
        ; 
        true,
    recordz( Key, NewValue, _ )).
```

**EDIT** 
You can also use the global vars, backtrackable and non-backtrackable.
e.g.
`nb_setval/2, nb_getval/2`

So your first statement could look as follows

```
:- nb_setval(score, 0),    
    nb_setval(multiplier, 1), 
    nb_setval(reward, 0), 
    nb_setval(prior_prob, 1),

    nb_setval(args, [score, multiplier, reward, prior_prob]).
```

**EDIT2**

`=/2` is the predicate's calling the Prolog's unification procedure `unify/2`.
If you mean under *dictionary overwriting* the reassign of a variable group you can do that with either of the solutions :

**EDIT3**

% I think it should be like this:

```
update_dict(Dict):- 
    update(args, Dict). 

update(Key, Val):- 
    (nb_getval(Key, OldVal), 
    exists(Val, OldVal)) -> true; 
    nb_setval(Key, Val). 

update(Key, Val, Dict):- 
    update_dict( Dict ), 
    update( Key, Val ). 

exists(Val, OldVal) :-
    nonvar(OldVal),
    same_term(Val, OldVal).

%======================================   
lookup_dict( Dict):- 
    lookup(args, Dict). 

lookup(Key, Val):- 
    nb_getval(Key, OldVal),
    exists( Val, OldVal ) -> 
       true
        ; 
        nb_setval(Key, Val).

lookup( Key, Val, Dict ):- 
     lookup_dict( Dict ), 
     lookup( Key, Val ).
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need!! Many thanks for taking time to read the post and sharing the answer! @Anton Danilov

Comment: Also, with the second approach, the "update" and "lookup" functions become the following (correct me if wrong): `update(Key,Val):-!, nb_setval(args,Args),member(Key,Args),nb_setval(Key,Val).` and `lookup(Key,Val):-nb_getval(Key,Val).`.

Comment: What's the purpose of updating a value and a dictionary at the same time, as in `update(Key,Val,Dict)`? If we do `update(reward,1,Dict)`, we'll get "true", and no value returned for "Dict". There is also the danger of accidentally overwrite the dictionary, such as if we do `update(reward,1,dict)`. So what's the benefit of keeping "Dict" as a third argument in "update"?

Comment: @vw511 - you can comment out these predicates having Dict arg. `update/3` and `lookup/3`. It's just a Demo.  ))